# js Array.prototype.filter.call() - can someone explain me how this piece of code works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Can someone explain how this piece of code works?
The output is a vector with the letters of input but without repetition.

```
var uniqueInOrder = function (iterable) {
  return [].filter.call(iterable, (function (a, i) {
    return iterable[i - 1] !== a
  }));
}
console.log(uniqueInOrder("aaaaaBBBDSJJJJ"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break this down:
`return [].filter.call(iterable,(function (a, i) { return iterable[i - 1] !== a }));`

*. we are returning an Array.

*. using `.filter.call(iterable,` allows us to use the `Array.prototype.filter` method on the `iterable` which is a string (making the function treat the string as an array of chars) as the first parameter that `call` gets is the context.

*. the filter function returns a subset of the array for each element that returns true. so when doing `return iterable[i - 1] !== a` every time we check if the element in index `i-1` which is basically the previous element is not equal to the current element which is `a` if it is not equal we return true so the `a` element is a part of the subset array which is being returned.

note that the easiest way for you to understand is **debug** just paste this code in the developer toolbar console:

```
 var uniqueInOrder = function (iterable)
    {debugger;
      return [].filter.call(iterable,(function (a, i) { return iterable[i - 1] !== a }));
    }
    console.log(uniqueInOrder("aaaaaBBBDSJJJJ"))
```

Comment: I think you have this part slightly wrong: *`return []` so we are returning an Array.*

Comment: So if I understand it correctly,  with  {filter.call(iterable,} Im am telling to execute the callback on the variable iterable? I dont understand why the callback has 2 arguments, what they are.

Comment: Exactly, the filter method on the iterable. So the callback happens on each element of iterable

Comment: ok thanks.  I still dont get it about the arguments of callback. I Understand what happens in the {} of the callback, but how are a and i assigned?

Comment: The filter method injects those 2 arguments to the callback method

Comment: what is the mechanism by which an array method knows how to treat a string as a series of chars?

Comment: Is `[].filter.call(iterable,...` equivalent to `iterable.filter()`?

Comment: no, iterable here is just a variable name of type String so it doesn't have .filter method on it

Answer (score 0):

@daymos Callback is invoked with three arguments.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refrain from posting only a link as your answer, as links die over time.  Take the relevant information from the article and post it here with an explanation.